# When Frankensteining ciphers together, why does order matter?

Tags: algorithm-design

In a comment on [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75388/13185), Cort Ammon states

> I have heard interesting solutions to these issues involving encrypting something with a proper tested algorithm first (*not* second), and then encrypting it with your home brew solution with an unrelated key. It seems legit, but I can't actually claim I've analyzed that particular configuration to see if it actually works or not.

Why does order matter?  What makes encrypting with AES and then re-encrypting with the Caesar Cipher better than encrypting with the Caesar Cipher and then re-encrypting with AES?